# Creating an object of a class from another class using NetBeans in Java

Tags: java, object, netbeans

I am using NetBeans and am trying to create an object of **class Two** in **class One**.
class Two is in a file **Two.java** and class One is in a file **One.java**.

One.java

```
public class One 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            Two obj = new Two();
            obj.ReceiveData("Hello");
    }
}
```

Two.java

```
public class Two 
{
    public void ReceiveData(String str)
    {
      System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

Both of the files(One.java and Two.java) are within the same (default)package.

Same Package

[image: Same Package]

However, i am getting an error stating,

> cannot find symbol: class Two, location class One

When both the classes are in the same file, there is no error and class Two object can be created in class One.
Where am i wrong?

Comment: Realy import is needed here

Comment: thank you for the quick response Maroun and Sinclair. Shouldn't the classes in the same package be able to refer to each other without using import? am not able to do so..

Comment: thank you Satya, as i understand it, import is used to refer to a class from another package, isnt it so?